# Android NDK -stdio.h : sys/cdefs.h not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

i build one sample native application in android ,when i compiling using ndk -bild  i get a linkage problem.i got the following error

```
    arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -c -O2 -w -ansi -D_POSIX_SOURCE -I. -I../bozorth/include -   I./include/ "-D __MSYS__" "-D__NBISLE__"  src/BiomServerComponent.c -o src/BiomServerComponent.o
    In file included from src/BiomServerComponent.c:1:0:
    f:\android-ndk-r8b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/include-fixed/stdio.h:50:23: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    Makefile:25: recipe for target `src/BiomServerComponent.o' failed
```

I don't found sys/cdefs.h or sys/_types.h,but i locate the stdio.h in following path

```
F:\android-ndk-r8b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include
```

any body know ,how to link this standard header files ,

Comment: Your command line is too short. Please show your `Android.mk` file, something is wrong there.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

EDIT re: the latest question revision:

The real question is - why is the compiler looking for header files under `toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.6.x-google\include-fixed`, when they are really at `platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include`? Is there a rogue -I option somewhere? The `include` folder under `toolchains`, that the OP is having trouble with, looks crippled; it's probably an artifact of the GCC distribution. The real NDK header folder is elsewhere.

Comment: The output provided by the author emphasizes NDK-r8b.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, it would seem that your clarification is that you're trying to #include header files which the NDK does not support; keep in mind that the NDK does not provide 100% coverage of what you commonly expect to find in a compiler.

If you are directly including these files, you should probably include `<sys/types.h>` instead.

Comment: the build log shows that the problematic include was in a system header, `stdio.h`.

Comment: @Alex indeed it does. On my system, both cdefs.h and _types.h are present in the NDK tree as well, though I only have r4 installed, not r7.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Make sure to set the *--sysroot* flag properly. Otherwise, the ndk will default to the directory *toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.6.x-google\include-fixed* directory after failing to find the directory at *platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include*. I had the same problem.